# How to extract from Text and match from another query

Tags: sql, regex, join, teradata

I have a table with airport sequences (AIRPRT_SERIES) like   SFO/ATL/GRU or PIT/ATL/GIG/VIX.  I would like to find all matches in this field (in this case ATL/GRU and  ATL/GIG) that match another table where I have those flights (Hub: ATL Spoke:GIG).  Problem is that I don't know how to pass or join my tables to make this happen.

This is a query that does half of what I want.   The problem is that there are no fields in either table that match (other than when I extract them) so I don't know how to do the join.

```
select 
*
from LEG_OD leg
inner join myMarkets mkts
on leg.nondir=mkts.nd_arp -- Current condition but not what I want/need
WHERE 
        REGEXP_SIMILAR(AIRPRT_SERIES ,  '[A-Z]{3}/('||mkts.SPOKE||'/'||mkts.Hub||'/|'||mkts.Hub||'/'||mkts.Spoke||'/)[A-Z]{3}' )=1  

AND 
 leg.year_month  BETWEEN '20160101' AND '20160112'
```

**LEG_OD Fields**:   AIRPRT_SERIES, Passengers, nondir

**myMarkets**:   Hub, Spoke, Distance,nd_arp

I would like to keep the REGEXP_SIMILAR condition as this is part of a larger query.

Comment: Your current RegEx will only match exactly four airports with the hub/spoke combination in the middle, is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  I have another clauses that did not include in this query to make it more legible (if the solution works with this, it will work with the others).  I am mostly interested in how to pass the values to the regex.

Comment: You could use Andrew's approach with StrTok, but as the position of the airports is known/fixed you better extract it using Substring. And because the order hub/spoke or spoke/hub is not known you can apply Least/Greatest: ` ON Greatest(Substr(AIRPRT_SERIES, 5,3), Substr(AIRPRT_SERIES, 9,3)) = Greatest(hub, spoke)
AND    Least(Substr(AIRPRT_SERIES, 5,3), Substr(AIRPRT_SERIES, 9,3)) = Least(hub, spoke)`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE`.  Taking your LEG_OD table, we can split out the individual elements from airport_series.

```
select
d.* from TABLE (strtok_split_to_table (LEG_OD.<some sort of id column>,LEG_OD.AIRPORT_SERIES, '/')
returns (outkey integer, tokennum integer,toke varchar(3) character set unicode)) as d
order by 1,2
```

That will get you a row for each element in the airport_series column.

If I understand your data correctly, you could then join on those values.